# RSA-210 factorization

Tags: number-theory

[RSA-210](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_numbers#RSA-210) has been factored

```
N = 245246644900278211976517663573088018467026787678332759743414451715061600830038587216952208399332071549103626827191679864079776723243005600592035631246561218465817904100131859299619933817012149335034875870551067
```

in two 105-digit prime numbers. http://www.mersenneforum.org/showpost.php?p=354259

```
 435958568325940791799951965387214406385470910265220196318705482144524085345275999740244625255428455944579
 562545761726884103756277007304447481743876944007510545104946851094548396577479473472146228550799322939273
```

---

How did we know RSA-210 was a [semiprime](http://oeis.org/A001358)?

Comment: In RSA $n = p \times q$, where $p$ and $q$ are picked using two large primes by algorithm, [*RSA Algotithm*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(algorithm)). This is known as the [*Integer Factorization Problem*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization).

Answer (score 3):

No one "knew" that RSA-210 was semiprime.  Not even those running the contest know what the factors of the number are.  It's just that they assume their algorithms for generating the contest numbers are correct (to enough probability) and so the numbers they post are almost certainly semiprime.

It's only after factoring that everyone else knows a number is semiprime, unless some incredible result comes up in number theory algorithms which isn't likely.

Comment: Do you mean by "almost certainly" that their algorithm for generating the contest numbers was probabilistic or that they cannot be sure (as one never can) that their implementation/algorithm did not contain a bug?

Comment: Probabilistic algorithm for generating 2 primes.